# How do I suppress the \newpage or \cleardoublepage for a new chapter?

Tags: spacing

I am using: `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`.

Calling my pieces of content sections gets an undesirable treatment in the table of contents.  Designating them as chapters makes the ToC look right, but brings along with it `\cleardoublepage` littering what should be a 48 page pamphlet with empty pages and an  unnecessarily expensive-to-print 72 page result file.

I would like to somehow overwrite the `\chapter` (macro, is it???) so that I can begin the next `\section` / `\chapter` on the same page where the last one ended; while still getting them included in the ToC and still allowing me to organize them for `\import{}` statements in my primary file.

Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this, please?  Any help would be appreciated.

-- Hugh

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Use an article class and section.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}` ?

Comment: From your description you would be better to use \section rather than \chapter then use article not book

Comment: report class would get rid of a few pages.  `\let\cleardoublepage=\relax` would be a risky quick fix.  Note that you can use `\renewcommand{\sectionname}{Chapter}` etc with the article/section approach.

Comment: You could try the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) with the `article` option which will make chapters look like sections. `\documentclass[article, your-current-options]{memoir}`